# Evaluation of integral and approximate solution

Tags: calculus

I want to integrate an expression like below

$$\cos(\phi+t-bt^2+b^2t^3),$$

with respect to $t$, where $b$ and $\phi$ are constants, but I’m not getting any help or clue.

The exact function is something like this
$$\cos(\phi+\eta\exp(-b\eta)),$$ where $\eta$ is a function of time and we need to integrate the above with respect to time.

Comment: Without $t^3$, no problem. With $t^3$, I doubt about a possible solution.

Comment: Would you tell us the limits of integration?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Differentiation under integral sign(Feynman's way)??

Comment: @LuckyChouhan. This would make the problem just worse (I think)

Comment: @Claude, $\cos(t^2)$ has no elementary antiderivative, does it? Similar to $e^{t^2}$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson. Elementary no but simple (Fresnel integrals as you know it). I wonder if, at a time, the definition of elementary will not need to be revised. Cheers. :-)

Comment: What's the purpose of the approximation? Do you need to have some closed form expression involving the parameters $\phi$ and $b$? or do you just need to be able to compute the integral for a given set of parameters? For the latter you are better off with numerical integration.

Comment: @PierreCarre, I need to use the solution further to evaluate other quantities further. Thats why numerical integration is not going to help me. There is no limits of integration  at present, however we can consider from 0 to t

Comment: @DinkarMishra you want solution for indefinite integration?????????????

Comment: @LuckyChouhan yes